# Asp page won't open

Tags: asp-classic

I have this web page that works fine in one webhost but not in the other one.
Here it works fine: http://www.kollelbaaleibatim.com/pweb.asp
Here it doesn't work: http://pmustangs.com/pweb.asp

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at response header from both servers, I can say that

kollelbaaleibatim.com is served by: `Microsoft-IIS/7.0`

While

pmustangs.com is served by `Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635`

Are you sure your second server supports classic ASP?

Comment: Can Apache even support classic ASP? I thought ASP was IIS-only, but maybe times have changed.

Comment: Got it! I see that I did a simple mistake thinking this webhost support asp classic. I appreciate your help. TY.

Answer (score 0):

Your pmustangs host has not turned on ASP processing. It hasn't mapped the .asp extension to the ASP.DLL script processor.

Comment: So is it easy to do, or I need to move my file elsewhere? TY.